# spark-cassandra-connector for Spark 1.4 and Cassandra 3.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

Spark-Cassandra experts: Will Apache Spark 1.4 work with Apache Cassandra 3.0 in Datastax installations?. We are considering several options for migrating  DSE 4.8 (Spark 1.4 and Cassandra 2.1) to DSE 5.0 (Spark 1.6 and Cassandra 3.0). One option is to update Cassandra Cluster to DSE 5.0 and leave Spark cluster on DSE 4.8. This means we have to make Apache Spark 1.4 work with Apache Cassandra 3.0. We use https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector  versions 1.4 (DSE 4.8) and 1.6(DSE 5.0). Has someone tried using Spark 1.4 (DSE 4.8) with Cassandra 3.0 (DSE 5.0) ?.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post a good question, so that you recieve helpful responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from the Maven Central, Spark Cassandra Connector 1.4.5 did use the version 2.1.7 of the Java driver. According the [compatibility matrix in official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/native_protocol/), the driver 2.1.x won't work with Cassandra 3.0... You can of course test it, but I doubt that it will work - driver is usually backward compatible, but not forward compatible...

I recommend to perform migration to DSE 5.0, and then move to 5.1 fast enough, as 5.0 could be EOL soon.

P.S. If you have more questions, I recommend to join the DataStax Academy Slack - there is a separate channel about spark cassandra connector there.